# Present Mysql data in seperated tables depands on value

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have got Ajax, jQuery script that do AutoCheck if data has changed and load this data without refreshing page.

Now I would like to present this data in seperated tables depands on value of on cell in the mysql row.

```
function get_news(){ 

    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT t1.* FROM fandb t1 JOIN (SELECT tableno, MAX(add_date) add_date FROM fandb GROUP BY tableno ASC) t2 ON t1.tableno = t2.tableno AND t1.add_date = t2.add_date WHERE AND id<>1;')){

        $return = '';

        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
        if (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='1') { $area_new='STARTER'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='2') { $area_new='MAIN COURSE'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='3') { $area_new='DESSERT'; }
        if (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='1') { $class_new='id="kitchen_tab_starter"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='2') { $class_new='id="kitchen_tab_main"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='3') { $class_new='id="kitchen_tab_dessert"'; } elseif (''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).''=='0') { $class_new='id="kitchen_tab_done"'; }
            $return .= '<button '.$class_new.'><div class="fontbig">'.htmlspecialchars($r->tableno).'</div><div class="fontsmall">'.$area_new.'</font></div></button>';
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to present data depend on value of title column in database.
So if `title` is equal 1 then it is presented in the top div if `title` is equal 2 than in second div and if 3 than in third div.

I was trying to play with `foreach` loop in the `while()` loop however it doesn't do the trick.

Have you got ideas so I can work out this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I doubt that someone could answer this question not knowing all the details about how you handle this data later. But since it's already on StackOverflow I try to answer it, so others could get something from this too.

If you indeed use my script from http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii/ then you should notice that there is a JSON involved. You should use this to your advantage, because in PHP you don't control where the code will be placed in your HTML when you make an AJAX request. Not directly anyway.

You control that in that JS part. So, you could do that by making for example 3 different requests that on the "success" will add the response in the relevant div, or pass a variable that will indicate where to put this response.

Assuming that you want to update few places at the same time with one request, the easiest way would be to return an array in get_news() like this:

```
$return = array();
while($r = $result->fetch_object()){

    /* I don't know what exactly is in title but if there 
    are only numbers (integers), then just use a number 
    and not string and htmlspecialchars, note that strings 
    like "lorem ipsum" will be changed to 0, and "123 ABC" to 123. 
    You currently compare this to numbers so that's why I brought this up. 
    Use with caution. */

    switch((int)$r->title){
        case 1:
            $arr= array(

                /* the id of a div that you want to update */
                'destination'=>'#kitchen_tab_starter',

                /* the html that will replace current html
                in div#kitchen_tab_starter */
                'html'=>'<some html you want to embed if its 1>'

            );
            $return[] = $arr;
        break;
        case 2:
            $arr= array(
                'destination'=>'#kitchen_tab_main',
                'html'=>'<some html you want to embed if its 2>'
            );
            $return[] = $arr;
        break;
        /* ... and so on */
    }
}
return $return;
```

This is changed to JSON object in the checker.php file and that JSON is sent back in the response. So now you have your response that is an object like this:

```
response = {
  update:true,
  news:{
    0:{
      destination:'div-id',
      html:'<some html>'
    },
    1:{
      destination:'div-id',
      html:'<some html>'
    }
  }
}
```

And now you need to change this simple line:

```
$('#message-list').html(response.news);
```

that is changing your current html to something similar to this

```
//check if we have something inside news
if(response.news.length>0){
  $.each(response.news, function(i, item) {
    $(item.destination).html(item.html);
  });
}
```

This is a concept you should be able to implement to update more than one div.

Comment: So I have done as above added to db.php coding from the top to the `get_news();` function than I have eddited checker file to add rule. and it does not work. Im sure Im doing something wrong but cant work out what.

Comment: At the end I have duplicated functions and changed their names.
Im sure this is not the best solution but works for me:)